# Git commit lost after merge

Tags: git

We have 3 branches (A, B, C) as below:

```
---\--A1--\------Am------Merge1---An---Merge2---
    \      \              /             /
     \      \--C1---C2---/             /
      \                               /
       \--B1--------------Bn---------/
```

The problem appears at Merge2. Some commit on branch C ( **not all but some**, let's say C2) is lost on branch A after Merge2, which is present between Merge1 and Merge2.

When doing Merge2, there is only one file conflict, which not relates to the lost commit (C2). And we resolve the confilict and finish the merge successfully.

**It seems like C2 is reversed by Merge2 on branch A, without any log.**

What happened? What might be the cause to this situation?

Comment: What does `git branch --contains C2` output?

Comment: @ElpieKay: "git branch --contains C2" outputs A and C. A is master in fact.

Comment: @reniaL If so, C2 is still reached by master. The commit itself is not lost from master. If C2's changes are gone, you could run `git log master -- <C2's file>` to see if any other commit has reversed the changes. `git blame -- <C2's file>` may also help.

Comment: @ElpieKay: I know what u mean. But here comes the weird thing: "git log master -- <C2's file>" contains NO C2, nor any commits that reversed C2.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What you mean is not that the commit *itself* is lost, but rather that the *changes made* (to some file) in that commit have been reverted (un-made).

It's worth noting here that commits don't really "make changes to" files.  Instead, each commit stores a complete set of files, whole and intact.  When you ask Git to show you some commit (let's say its ID is `c2c2c2...`):

```
$ git show c2c2c2
```

what Git does is:

1. extract commit `c2c2c2...`
2. extract the parent commit of `c2c2c2...`
3. produce a diff listing from parent to child

This is how Git manages to show you what changed: it compares "what you had just before that commit" to "what you had as of that commit".  (Git can do this pretty quickly, optimized-ly, because every file is reduced to a unique hash "fingerprint", and Git can first just compare the fingerprints (hashes).  If the hashes are the same, the files are the same.  It only really has to bother extracting the actual file data if the hashes differ.)

This process—saving whole files, instead of accumulating changes—is called "storing snapshots".  (Other version control systems tend to accumulate changes, which is called "storing deltas".  They do this because saving the *changes* to files obviously takes far less space than saving the files.  Git sneaks around the issue in a clever way and winds up using less disk space than older delta-based version control systems anyway.)

#### Why "Git stores snapshots, not deltas" matters so much here

A *merge commit* is special, in one particular and obvious way.  Look at your own diagram and consider `Merge1`.  What commit comes right before it?

The answer here is that both `Am` and `C2` come "right before" `Merge1`.  That is, commit `Merge1` has *two* parent commits.

If you ask Git to show you commit `Merge1`, which parent should it compare-with?

Here's where things get particularly odd.  The two commands `git log -p` and `git show` *seem* very similar.  In fact, they *are* very similar.  The one obvious difference is that `git log -p` shows more than one commit, while `git show` shows just the one commit you tell it to show.  You can run `git log -n 1 -p <commit>` to show just the one commit, and now it *seems* like these are *exactly* the same.

They're not!

When you use `git show` on a merge commit, Git tries to solve the "what commit to compare against" problem by comparing, simultaneously, against *both* parents.  The resulting diff is called a *combined diff*.

When you use `git log -p` on a merge commit, though, Git just throws up its metaphorical hands, says "I can't show patches against two parents", and gives up and goes on to the next commit.  ***In other words, `git log -p` doesn't even bother trying diffs for the merge.***

#### But wait, there's more

Now, in this case you might be tempted to see if you can figure out what happened to your file from commit `c2c2c2...` using `git show` on the two merges—in particular, on `Merge2`, where the changes got reverted.  But `git show` produces, by default, a *combined diff*, and a combined diff deliberately omits a lot of diff output.  In particular, a combined diff [lists only files which were modified from all parents](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_diff_format_for_merges).

Let's say the file where your changes from `C2` were reverted is file `f2`.  And, from the graph, the two parents of `Merge2` are `An` (which has `f2` the way you want it) and `Bn` (which doesn't).

What actually happened here is that, during the merge that created `Merge2`, you somehow told Git to use the version of `f2` from commit `Bn`.  That is, file `f2` in `Merge2` is exactly the same as file `f2` in `Bn`, and different from `f2` in commit `An`.

If you use `git show` to view `Merge2`, the combined diff will *skip* `f2`, because it is *the same* as the `f2` in `Bn`.

The same is true, only even worse, with `git log -p`: it skips the merge entirely, because it's just too hard to show diffs.

Even without `-p`, when you ask for "files changed", `git log` winds up doing the same thing—skipping the merge entirely.  That's why you can't see it in the log output.

(As an aside, the reason `git log master -- f2` never shows commit `C2` itself is that adding a file name to the options to `git log` turns on "history simplification".  In what I consider to be somewhat buggy behavior, Git winds up simplifying away *too much* history, so that it never shows commit `C2`.  Adding `--full-history` before the `-- f2` restores `C2` to the set of commits shown.  The merge is still missing, though, because `git log` skips it.)

#### How to see the change

There is a solution.  Both `git show` and `git log` take an additional flag, `-m`, which "splits" merges.  That is, instead of treating `Merge2` as a merge commit, these will break the merge into two "virtual commits".  One will be "`Merge2` vs `An`", and you will see all the differences between those two commits, and the other will be "`Merge2` vs `Bn`", and you will see all the differences between *those* two commits.  This will show that file `f2` got re-set to the way it is in `Bn`, losing the version from `C2` that appears in `An` but not in `Bn`.

(Include `--full-history` as well as `-m` to ensure that commit `C2` shows up as well.)

#### How this happened in the first place

This part is *not* clear, at all.  You said there was a merge conflict, though, which means `git merge` stopped and got manual assistance, from a human.  At some point during this assistance, the human probably updated the index with the version of file `f2` from `Bn` (or at least, a version of `f2` that did not have the change made back in `C2`).

This can happen during merges, and it's a bit insidious precisely *because* Git shows merges with these compressed (combined) diffs, or in the case of `git log -p`, not at all, by default.  It's something to watch out for, especially if a merge required manual conflict resolution.  In most cases, the way to catch this sort of merge error is with automated tests.  (Of course, not everything can be tested.)

Comment: "What actually happened here is that, during the merge that created Merge2, you somehow told Git to use the version of f2 from commit Bn." If this is true, then "git log f2" would not show C2 and Merge2 at all, correct? If correct, this is counter-intuitive....

Comment: `git log -- f2` won't show `Merge2` because `git log` doesn't look closely enough at merge commits to find changed files. It should still show commit `C2`, provided you have not used additional flags that disable this somehow (such as `--first-parent` or some cases of `--follow`). And, `git log -m -- f2` should show `Merge2 from An`: the split half of `Merge` diffed against commit `An`.

Comment: By my test, `git log -- f2` (no additional flags) does NOT show `C2`. And `git log -m -- f2` does NOT show `Merge2 from An`. It's like `C2` is gone for `f2` (including log and content), but `C2` log still exists on branch A.

Comment: Curious. When *does* `git log` show file `f2`? (i.e., from what starting-point does `C2` appear in the output of `git log -- f2`?) For instance, if you run `git log C2 -- f2`, that should show `C2`.

Comment: `git log` show `f2` at `C2`, since there are no further modification to `f2` (except `Merge2`). Running `git log C2 -- f2` does show `C2`, at the top. And, as I said above, `git log -- f2` does NOT show `C2`, it's weird, but confirmed.

Comment: Intriguing. I wonder if you've managed to uncover a bug in `git log`. If `git log C2 -- f2` shows `C2` and `git merge-base is-ancestor C2 HEAD` is true, `git log -- f2` should show `C2`.  If `HEAD` points to Merge2 and the graph is as shown, then C2 is an ancestor.

Comment: Sorry for late response. `HEAD` doesn't point to `Merge2` but is ahead of `Merge2` by some commits. And `git merge-base --is-ancestor C2 HEAD; echo $?` outputs `0` (which means true, right?). But `git log -- f2` just doesn't show `C2`. Not sure if it matters but, it's a minor modification of `C2`: a word `productKey` changed to `productkey`, nothing else.

Comment: HEAD being further ahead should not be a problem since Git should trace everything back (again assuming no commit-constraining operations like `--first-parent` or `--ancestry-path` that drop some commits) (and yes, `0` means true in shell exit status encoding).  This does seem rather baffling.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying details about git diff and merge commit. The remaining issue above is another topic and should be discussed elsewhere.

Comment: @reniaL: this has come up again in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768571/why-does-git-report-a-branch-as-containing-a-commit-but-the-commit-doesnt-appe and I think I understand it completely now: when you add a path name (`-- f2`) this turns on *history simplification*, which is (especially in this case) too aggressive and removes commit `C2` here. Add `--full-history` to see `C2` again.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I would consider these oversimplifications of changes bugs, wouldn't you?

Comment: @ADJenks: Sometimes people want them; sometimes people don't. I've never had much luck convincing the core Git team that my preferences are right :-) so all I can say is "know when to add `--full-history`".