# Why does git report a branch as containing a commit, but the commit doesn't appear to have been applied?

Tags: git

I have a scenario that's occurred on a Git repo that is very actively developed on and I'm trying to understand how it is possible.

Scenario:

I have feature branch `FeatureA`. A line was added to a file `file1.txt`, committed to this branch and pushed to the origin with commit hash `hash1`. `FeatureA` was subsequently merged into `master` and `develop`.

Running `git branch -a --contains hash1` lists `FeatureA`, `develop` and `master` as containing the commit, both remote and local branches.

However, the line is no longer contained in `file1.txt` in `develop`. Running `git log -- file1.txt` within the `develop` branch shows no sign of the commit, despite git reporting that it contains the commit. Trying to merge `FeatureA` into `develop` simply reports that there is nothing new to merge. I can't find any trace of the line being deleted in any commit.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on how this could be possible?

**EDIT:**

I just ran the following commands whilst in the develop branch:

> >git log | grep 8d42290f
>
> > commit 8d42290fe9458abb1ae4948a3a48bf11888bb69d
>
> >git show 8d42290f
>
> > commit 8d42290fe9458abb1ae4948a3a48bf11888bb69d
> >
> > diff --git a/file1.txt b/file1.txt
> >
> > index d0d0f80..b70238e 100644
> >
> > --- a/file1.txt
> >
> > +++ b/file1.txt
> >
> > [shows the addition made]
>
> >git branch -a --contains 8d42290f
>
> > master
> >
> > * develop
> >
> > [omitted other branches, but it's basically everywhere]
>
> > git log -- .\file1.txt
>
> > commit 24db30f63875fc70d1ccde3ceb5557ad84ca2ecb
> >
> > Author: [omitted]
> >
> > Date:   [omitted]
> >
> > [omitted]
> >
> > commit 13e2f168f77980bfa481295149c9df34afe0fa53
> >
> > Author: [omitted]
> >
> > Date:   [omitted]
> >
> > [omitted]

No trace of 8d42290f in the log for that file and no commit deleting the line.

Comment: I don't see how this mysterious scenario is possible. Could you possibly share the repository as a concrete example?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Are there any further diagnostics or checks I could perform to shed some light on this? Is it possible for some kind of corruption to occur? I did a fresh clone as well just to be doubly sure.

Comment: Are you certain of the path of file1.txt? try git log | grep hash1 to make sure the commit is in the tree

Comment: I just detailed some requested output in the question. Also, there is only one file1.txt in the entire repo, but I did double check the path as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it via command line, but I would use some graphic interface like gitg, look for the commit where featureA was merged inside develop to confirm the line is there, then I would go up commits one by one until the line dissapears.

Comment: Was the file later renamed?

Comment: Also try `git log --full-history --sparse -- file1.txt`

Comment: I think this might have solved the mystery. I didn't realise just how much git log prunes the list. Someone had removed the line as part of a bad merge conflict resolution. Thanks for your help. If you like to put it as an answer I'll mark it as resolved.