# Why some git commits lost after merge

Tags: git

There are several branches in one project (M branch is the master branch), like below:

```
------M1--\------Mm------Merge1-------------Mn--------------Merge2----Mo----Merge3-
           \              /                                  /               /                                         
            \--A1---A2---/                                  /               /                                         
                        \                                  /               / 
                         \                                /               /                                  
                          \------B1---B2-------B3---B4---/               /                                                    
                                            \                           /              
                                             \                         /                                                       
                                              \---------C1------C2----/
```

All the B1, B2, B3, B4 are related to modify one file.

The problem is, after the **Merge3**, although we can see the B1 and B2 change, but **B3 and B4** got lost in master, we cannot see the changelog, that file's content stays at B2.

But if we use the

```
git log --follow myfile.java
```

Then I can see all the changes, including B3 and B4

Anybody know why this happens, how to solve this issue

Comment: It could be that merge3 had conflicts where the resolution resulted in getting rid of B3 and B4 changes. Maybe consider redoing the merge? Create a branch at C2, create a duplicate of master at Mo, then merge the new C2 branch in it. It won't impact your real branches, but it'll maybe help understand how you got here.

Comment: Did you at some point revert a merge commit and tried to re-apply the merge?

Comment: @k0pernikus there no such revert change related to this file. We are still trying to figure out what has happened

Comment: @RomainValeri yes, that one solution. We decided to do it this way. Fortunately not many submissions

Answer (score 1):

**B3 and B4 was lost**

That's not true. B3 and B4 are present in the commit history, as `git log --follow myfile.java` suggests. The fact is B3 and B4's modification has been un-done during the merge.

**I have no log about that ?**

You didn't mentioned what was you method to check that, `log` or `show`.

*Short answer* : use `-m` flag

*Long answer* : I suggest you to read this very interesting answer about `log` and `show` in your context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466462/git-commit-lost-after-merge). The part of that (long) answer that you need to read :

> How to see the change ?
>   There is a solution. Both `git show` and `git log` take an additional flag, `-m`, which "splits" merges. That is, instead of treating `Merge2` as a merge commit, these will break the merge into two "virtual commits". One will be "`Merge2` vs `An`", and you will see all the differences between those two commits, and the other will be "`Merge2` vs `Bn`", and you will see all the differences between those two commits. This will show that file f2 got re-set to the way it is in `Bn`, losing the version from `C2` that appears in `An` but not in `Bn`.
>   (Include --full-history as well as -m to ensure that commit `C2` shows up as well.)

**How can I re-include B3 and B4 in master ?**

In this particular situation (already pushed stuff, reduced number of involving commits, no/small further changes) i would `cherry-pick` that two commits and put them on top of merge3

**How to avoid this situation in the future**

1. Dont push your work until you checked the merge result, so you can easily delete&redo
2. Rebase `C branch` on top of `B branch` before merge (avoid merge branches that doesn't directly fork from one to another)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The main problem is, the file is out of date. When somebody checkout master, he sees the file stays in A2, there are no A3 and A4 changes.

Comment: I edited my answer to solve your particular problem, and make it not appear again,  too.